# OrientDB shortest path with dynamic weight?

Tags: dijkstra, orientdb

I am trying to create a graph in OrientDB where the weight of edges has to be calculated on demand using data from another database. I would like to know if there is a way to do this, since all example I´ve seen use static weight properties, none of which is dynamic by nature.

If I could use a stored function as a property and have it evaluate each time I call shortestPath then it would solve my problem, but I haven´t found any documentation on this topic.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by OrientDB out of the box, even if it would be something nice to have. Could you open a new issue?

About the solution I suggest to clone the `OSQLFunctionDijkstra` class, do your changes and plug into OrientDB engine with a different name.